# Can we get the file content from a link inside an email

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have an automated flow which runs when an email is received, the email contain a link to access a file. so can we get the content of the file and store it inside sharepoint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extract a file link from an incoming email and upload to SharePoint.

Please refer to：
https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/b0411e3b55784b7fa6f476f56879e2e3/extract-a-file-link-from-an-incoming-email-and-upload-to-sharepoint/